# Count non-zero & zero values against groups in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like below:

```
docs          language   instance
example 1     python     25
example 2     JS         15
example 3     python     0
example 4     JS         34
example 5     python     0
example 6     JS         0
```

I am trying to group them by language and then count non zero values from column 'instance' using the below code:

```
df['language'].groupby(df['instance']).count()
```

But unfortunately, it counts all of them. I wish to create a separate df with zero and a separate df for a total count of nonzero values.

Expected output for zero cells against group:

```
language     zero count     
python        2
JS            1
```

Expected output for non-zero cells against group:

```
language     non-zero count     
python        1
JS            2
```

Is there any way in pandas to do a count on zero or non-zero values? Any other libraries or ways to do it would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

To count zeros:

```
df.groupby('language').agg(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())
```

To count non-zeros:

```
df.groupby('language').agg(lambda x: x.ne(0).sum())
```

Comment: This helps. :) Would be grateful if you could also recommend or share some docs or references to this.

Comment: @Natanspecialist - you might find `df['instance'].eq(0).groupby(df['language']).value_counts()` useful as well (with maybe an `.unstack()` afterwards)